# Elixir app working in iex but fail when try to mix run

Tags: postgresql, elixir, ecto

I am trying to create application with Elixir, Ecto without Pheonix.

mix.exs

```
defmodule Wtf.MixProject do
  use Mix.Project

  def project do
    [
      app: :wtf,
      version: "0.1.0",
      elixir: "~> 1.13",
      start_permanent: Mix.env() == :prod,
      deps: deps()
    ]
  end

  # Run "mix help compile.app" to learn about applications.
  def application do
    [
      extra_applications: [:logger, :postgrex, :ecto, :ecto_sql],
      mod: {Wtf.Application, []}
    ]
  end

  # Run "mix help deps" to learn about dependencies.
  defp deps do
    [
      {:postgrex, "~> 0.16.3"},
      {:ecto, "~> 3.8.4"},
      {:ecto_sql, "~> 3.8.3"},
      {:json, "~> 1.4"},
      {:jason, "~> 1.3.0"},
      {:ratatouille, "~> 0.5.0"},
      # {:dep_from_hexpm, "~> 0.3.0"},
      # {:dep_from_git, git: "https://github.com/elixir-lang/my_dep.git", tag: "0.1.0"}
    ]
  end
end
```

repo.ex

```erlang
defmodule Wtf.Repo do
  use Ecto.Repo,
    otp_app: :wtf,
    adapter: Ecto.Adapters.Postgres
end
```

application.ex

```erlang
defmodule Wtf.Application do
  # See https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Application.html
  # for more information on OTP Applications
  @moduledoc false

  use Application

  @impl true
  def start(_type, _args) do
    children = [
      # Starts a worker by calling: Wtf.Worker.start_link(arg)
      # {Wtf.Worker, arg}
      Wtf.Repo
    ]

    # See https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Supervisor.html
    # for other strategies and supported options
    opts = [strategy: :one_for_one, name: Wtf.Supervisor]
    Supervisor.start_link(children, opts)
  end
end
```

config.exs

```erlang
import Config

config :wtf, Wtf.Repo,
  database: "wtf_database",
  username: "wtf",
  password: "wtf",
  hostname: "localhost",
  port: "5050",
  log: false

config :wtf, ecto_repos: [Wtf.Repo]
```

wtf.ex

```erlang
defmodule Wtf do
  import Ecto.Query, warn: false

  alias Wtf.{Repo, Data}

  def hello do
    Repo.all(WtfData)
  end
end
```

Below I am attaching list of my files in project like you can see that is just basic setup for querying database. When I run `iex -S mix` app is loading properly and I can query database all CRUD working fine, when I do `Wtf.Repo.all(Wtf.Data)` I am getting all 3 rows which I have in database.

But when I am trying to run this app with `mix run lib/wtf.ex` I am getting an error

> function Repo.all/1 is undefined (module Repo is not available)

I was looking in the google how to solve it and it seems like I am doing everything like it should be done. I follow few examples but always the same issue. Can some explain me what is wrong with it? What am I missing?

Comment: `mix run <file>` is used to run a `.exs` file. Maybe you want `mix run -e "Wtf.hello()"`?

Comment: @Dogbert running that `mix run -e "Wtf.hello()"` gives me the same error, nothing change

Comment: You need to build a release; look at https://hexdocs.pm/mix/1.13/Mix.Tasks.Release.html

Comment: @RogerLipscombe So I need to build release each time I need to test change in my app? That seems very inconvenient.

Comment: @RogerLipscombe please avoid posting comments without explicitly specifying you are uncertain in the proposal if you don’t actually know the answer. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

*Sidenote:* of course you don’t need to build a release unless you want to run a release.

The below part of `mix.exs` defines the application within your project and its entry point.

```elixir
def application do
  [
    extra_applications: [:logger, :postgrex, :ecto, :ecto_sql],
#   ⇓⇓⇓⇓⇓⇓⇓⇓⇓⇓⇓⇓⇓⇓⇓⇓⇓⇓⇓⇓⇓ THIS
    mod: {Wtf.Application, []}
  ]
end
```

Instead of running an explicit file with `mix run ‹file›`, do [`mix run`](https://hexdocs.pm/mix/Mix.Tasks.Run.html) without a parameter, which is, according to docs,

> can be used to start the current application dependencies, the application itself, and optionally run some code in its context.

Comment: running `mix run` (without any file) give me the same error `Repo.all/1 is undefined (module Repo is not available)`

Comment: In what file? Please share the whole error message.

Comment: in my post there is only one place where I am using `Repo.all` method, look above. But if you need entire error here it goes `== Compilation error in file lib/wtf.ex == ** *(UndefinedFunctionError) function Repo.all/1 is undefined (module Repo is not available) Repo.all(CaseData) lib/wtf.ex:11: (file) (elixir 1.13.4) lib/kernel/parallel_compiler.ex:346: anonymous fn/5 in Kernel.ParallelCompiler.spawn_workers/7`

Comment: Usually doing `mix run` and running `iex -S mix` will both use the default compilation environment `dev` so it's odd that you're seeing a compile error when doing `mix run`.  If you delete the the `_build` directory and re-run `iex -S mix`, do you get a compile error?  Does the app compile in the `test` env (e.g. by running `mix test`)?